# Second order non homogeneous differential equation (hard)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could not find the solution of this expression.
$$y''+(3x^2-1/x)y'=A/x;    A=const.$$

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If this is your equation, I am not surprised that you have problems with it.*

First, reduce the order, using $z=y'$ to get
$$z'+\left(3 x^2-\frac{1}{x}\right) z=\frac{a}{x}$$ For the first part, that is to say $$z'+\left(3 x^2-\frac{1}{x}\right) z=0$$ it is quite simple since separable and get $$\frac {z'}z=\frac{1}{x}-3x^2\implies \log(z)=\log(x)-x^3+c\implies z=c\, x\, e^{-x^3}$$ Now, for the complete equation, use the variation of parameter which leads to $$e^{-x^3} x c'=\frac{a}{x}\implies  c'=\frac{a\, e^{x^3}}{x^2}\implies c=-\frac{a \left(e^{x^3}+x \, \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3},-x^3\right)\right)}{x}+d$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function. This makes 
$$z=e^{-x^3} x \left(d-a \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3},-x^3\right)\right)-a$$ which, I am afraid, is probably impossible to integrate.

At least,at this point, you can use numerical methods.